# Database Migration with Liquibase using different DBMS

Tags: mysql, oracle, migration

Our customer is using Oracle and we want to use MySQL for development. Therefore our MySQL Scheme has to be in sync with Oracle. I tried to use Liquibase, but I get problems at the time of applying a changeset because of the db specific sql and different column types like NUMBER <-> BIGINT or VARCHAR <-> VARCHAR2

Am I using these tools wrong? How to solve this type of problem?

Comment: Use Oracle for development? Seriously, you should be developing on the same DBMS that you (intend to) use in production.

Comment: Colin is completly right. This will definetly will bust your app. Oracle has some differences to Mysql especially with varchar. In Oracle Null == '' and I think there will be other issues.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I agree with you, but on defense of the OP, I would bet that this is probably the case where his client bought 1 Oracle license (and only one) and those are their requirements, not OP's ideal situation.

Comment: @jynus Yes, it is like that. The client prefers our software with a Oracle. So we have a test and prod Oracle DB. Internaly we use our Software with MySql

Comment: Then we add a change request of the client and sometimes with db changes. Later we need to sync our MySql scheme to the Oracle. That makes it difficult

Comment: @GedankenNebel I do not have an answer for you, but only 2 pointers: This will not solve your problem at all, but PostgreSQL tries to be a closer replacement than MySQL for Oracle (this is said by a MySQL guy). Check Tungsten: https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/ It is not a migration tool, but a hybrid replication, maybe that can be helpful somehow.

Comment: IANAL but I have always thought Oracle was free for development but requires license only in production.

Comment: there's a xe edition of oracle. most of the standard scenarios can be developed, but I think it's limited to a single schema, which can be troublesome in certain scenarios. It's already difficult to keep two seperate schemas like test and prod in sync with the same dbms. so think really about using xe or a real oracle also for dev.